# How do i read only value attr?

Tags: javascript

I want make value attribute to read-only and i do these code but not work ??

Need help ?

```js
const obj = {
  name: "karl"
}
const origName = obj.name;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get() {
    return origName + 2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead use the `writable` property of the property descriptor, which prevents the need for a get accessor:

```js
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {
  value: "karl",
  writable: false
  get() {
    return origName + 2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add "writebale" key;
Like this;

```
 Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
        value: "karl",
        writable: false
    });
```